# How to configure LDAP on Spark-Thrift server on AWS EMR?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-thriftserver

Note that we are not talking about hiveserver2, or hive-thrift server here.
If anyone has experience with this, I want to configure LDAP auth on spark-thrift server. I am using AWS EMR as my cluster.
I am able to start the server and query using it, but without any username or password. Not even sure where to specify authentication related properties. There's just very little documentation on this stuff.

Looking forward to hear from anyone who has experience doing this.

Answer (score 1):

1. copy the hive-site.xml from your ~/hive/conf directory to your ~/spark/conf/ directory.
2. you need to configure egress rules to allow your EMR cluster to connect to your LDAP server/ip/port.

As per official documentation from hiveserver2 :
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2

*Set following for LDAP mode:
hive.server2.authentication.ldap.url – LDAP URL (for example, ldap://hostname.com:389).
hive.server2.authentication.ldap.baseDN – LDAP base DN. (Optional for AD.)
hive.server2.authentication.ldap.Domain – LDAP domain. (Hive 0.12.0 and later.)
See User and Group Filter Support with LDAP Atn Provider in HiveServer2 for other LDAP configuration parameters in Hive 1.3.0 and later.*

hive-site.xml – changes :

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
    <value>LDAP</value>
    <description>
      Expects one of [nosasl, none, ldap, kerberos, pam, custom].
      Client authentication types.
        NONE: no authentication check
        LDAP: LDAP/AD based authentication
        KERBEROS: Kerberos/GSSAPI authentication
        CUSTOM: Custom authentication provider
                (Use with property hive.server2.custom.authentication.class)
        PAM: Pluggable authentication module
        NOSASL:  Raw transport
    </description>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.authentication.ldap.url</name>
    <value>ldaps://changemetoyour.ldap.url:5000</value>
    <description>
      LDAP connection URL(s),
      this value could contain URLs to mutiple LDAP servers instances for HA,
      each LDAP URL is separated by a SPACE character. URLs are used in the
       order specified until a connection is successful.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.authentication.ldap.baseDN</name>
    <value>changeme.mydomain.com</value>
    <description>LDAP base DN</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.authentication.ldap.Domain</name>
    <value/>
    <description/>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.authentication.ldap.groupDNPattern</name>
    <value/>
    <description>
      COLON-separated list of patterns to use to find DNs for group entities in this directory.
      Use %s where the actual group name is to be substituted for.
      For example: CN=%s,CN=Groups,DC=subdomain,DC=domain,DC=com.
    </description>
  </property>
```